# Conditional Statement + UITableView: Repeat values in array over and over

Tags: arrays, uitableview, conditional-statements

I found this hard to put a title on so please feel free to modify it.

I have an array that contains 5 `CGSizes` that I use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
 NSArray *mElements = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:
                      CGSizeMake(600.0, 900.0)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, 800.0)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(546.0, 1032.0)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, 700.0)],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, 800.0)],
                      nil];
```

I currently have it that a random size is taken from the array and applied to each cell, giving it a staggered layout. However the problem is that if I reload the `UITableView` all the rows will have different sizes, which is obvious because it will pick a random value each time.

```
int random = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) mElements.count);
CGSize size =[[mElements objectAtIndex:random] CGSizeValue];
```

However the effect I want is that `row` 0 will always have the same size, possibly the index 0 of the array. Then `row` 1 to have the value at index 1, and then row 2 to have the value at index 2, and so on. I would then like the `row` at index 4 to have the value at index 0 of the array (so the array starts again). I have tried this, but it requires too much hardcoding.

```
if (indexPath.item%2 && !indexPath.item%4) {

    size =[[mElements objectAtIndex:1] CGSizeValue];
}
else if(indexPath.item%3 && !indexPath.item%6){
    size =[[mElements objectAtIndex:2] CGSizeValue];

}
else if(indexPath.item%4){

    size =[[mElements objectAtIndex:2] CGSizeValue];

}
//... and so on
```

Im hoping to get help in creating a dynamic conditional state where I do not have to hard code every possible `row` index in the table. I can't seem to get my head around it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
size = [[mElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row % [mElements count]] CGSizeValue];
```

That'd give you a constant repeating pattern all the way down.
Number of rows could be

```
return [mElements count]*ROW_MULTIPLYER;
```

where

```
#define ROW_MULTIPLYER 10000
```

Comment: This seemed to do the job. There was no need to use the return value as my cells are dynamic from the web.

Comment: Cool. The numRows stuff is mainly if someone wants a pseudo infinite scrolling effect in the future... but you're right it doesn't apply to your question.